# Overriding bind method (Swift) - Err: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'addObserver'

Tags: swift, cocoa, binding, kvc

I'm pretty new to Swift and "Apple" programming so excuse me if my question is silly.

I'm trying to sub-class NSPopupButton in order to add an option for binding the menu items' image property.

I want to override the "bind" function:

```
override func bind(_ binding: NSBindingName, to observable: Any, withKeyPath keyPath: String, options: [NSBindingOption : Any]? = nil)
```

And to observe the "observable" parameter so this is the code I have written till now:

```
class WDPopupButton: NSPopUpButton
{
    static let ImageBindingContext: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: "imageContext")

    override func bind(_ binding: NSBindingName, to observable: Any, withKeyPath keyPath: String, options: [NSBindingOption : Any]? = nil)
    {
        if(binding == NSBindingName.image)
        {
            guard let observableObject = observable as AnyObject? else
            {
                return
            }

            observable.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: nil, context: WDPopupButton.ImageBindingContext)

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Value of type 'Any' has no member 'addObserver'
```

My question is, what do I need to do in order to call addObserver on the observable parameter?

As you can see, I did tried to cast observable to AnyObject type but then I received another error which I couldn't find a solution for.

I changed the addObserver line to:

```
observableObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: nil, context: WDPopupButton.ImageBindingContext)
```

And got:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

If casting observable to AnyObject is the solution, than what is this error means and what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `Any` instances do not have a method called `addObserver` that is why `observable.addObserver` does not work. (Value of type 'Any' has no member 'addObserver')

For the `observableObject.addObserver`, it is also similar as above, AnyObject does not have `addObserver` method.

SOLUTION:

Don't cast to `AnyObject`, cast to `NSObject`. `addObserver` is accessible via `NSObject` instances. Then access `addObserver` via the casted `NSObject` instance

```
guard let observableObject = observable as? NSObject else {return}

observableObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: nil, context: WDPopupButton.ImageBindingContext)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Maybe I should have said it earlier. The first thing I tried to do was to cast observable to NSObject but then I received another error:

    Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to type 'NSObject?' in coercion

Comment: Updated answer. your issue is the `?` should be after `as` and not NSObject